# Question on periodicity of function under certain conditions: $f(x+\lambda)=1+\sqrt{2f(x)-f(x)^2}$

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

> Check whether the function defined by $f(x+\lambda)=1+\sqrt{2f(x)-f(x)^2}$ for all $x$ belonging to the set of real numbers is periodic or not. If yes, then find its period ($\lambda >0$).

I can't understand how to approach this question can anyone please help.

**Answer:**
Period is $2\lambda$.

Comment: See what happens if you set $f(x)$ to $f(x+\lambda)$, i.e. find out what the value of the function is at $x + 2\lambda$.

Comment: @Lili FN but we also need to see that the term under root is positive

Comment: Does the question specify the range of the function?

Comment: Try showing that $f(x+n\lambda)=f(x)$, for $n=2$ or $3$

Comment: @Lili FN  no,it doesn't

Comment: @Z Ahmed but how can you predict answer before solving

Comment: @HariAnIndian then there is no need, since the range could be the complex numbers. And, in mathematics it is often like that - you try things which you think will work and go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x+\lambda)=1+\sqrt{2f(x)-(f(x))^2}$$

$$\Rightarrow(f(x+\lambda)-1)^2=2f(x)-(f(x))^2$$

$$\Rightarrow(f(x+\lambda))^2-2f(x+\lambda)=-(f(x)-1)^2$$

$$\Rightarrow f(x)=1+\sqrt{2f(x+\lambda)-(f(x+\lambda))^2}$$

Substituting $x$ by $x+\lambda$ in this equation, we get

$$\Rightarrow f(x+\lambda)=1+\sqrt{2f(x+2\lambda)-(f(x+2\lambda))^2}$$

On comparing this with the given equation, we get

$$\Rightarrow f(x)=f(x+2\lambda)$$

$\Rightarrow f(x)$ is periodic with period $2\lambda$.

Comment: Thanks @RiverX15